# Can't echo inside IF statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, echo

I'm having the darndest error... the code below is running as expected and visiting both halves of the `if` statement as expected (I can tell because I'm getting both "TRUE" and 'FALSE' added to the error log and getting them added above the output for the condition that caused them).

But when I visit the `TRUE` part of the `if`, it doesn't echo for some reason. I know that code section is not getting skipped (because the `error_log("TRUE");` still gets run).

### CODE SUMMARY:

Step through a list of states, output half of an HTML tag (conditionally add a middle bit), and then output the end half.

```
function createStateOptions($country, $state) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_state WHERE disabled != true AND deleted != true AND country = :country ORDER BY state ASC";
    $result = executeSQL($sql, array(':country' => $country));
    if (is_array($result)) {
        foreach ($result as $record) {
            echo '<option value="' . htmlentities($record["state"], ENT_QUOTES) . '" ';
            if($state == $record["state"]) {
                echo " selected";
                error_log("TRUE");
            } else {
                error_log("FALSE");
            }
            echo '>' . htmlentities($record["state"], ENT_QUOTES) . '</option>';
            error_log("'".$state."' == '".$record["state"]."'"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it echo anything? like the `option`?

Comment: Try `echo " selected='selected'";`

Comment: It echoes the stuff either side of the if statement (so yeah, the 'option' tag and everything else comes out, just not the ' selected'). I tried " selected='selected'" and it didn't show up in the page source either... it's a tricky one, huh?

Comment: Try using `print` instead of `echo`? (Just try, I have no reasonable explanation at the moment)

Comment: I know what you mean. Like changing ' selected' to 'selected="selected"', i had the thought to try that too, just in case. Tried both print and print_r ....no such luck. But hey, thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: For once in it's life, Internet Explorer is the Answer, not the problem.

The problem isn't in the PHP, so thank you for all your suggestions, they all needed to be tried, so thank you jSweazy, Sachleen, Imdad and Alvin Wong, you guys were great. Especially Imdad selected='selected' is the correct HTML format

IE shows me the original code. with an option tag selected and everything... but then Javascript changes the State options on page load to reflect the States for the country... and then doesn't pick one. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Try Building a string and then echoing all at end

```
function createStateOptions($country, $state) {
  $output = '';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_state WHERE disabled != true AND deleted != true AND country = :country ORDER BY state ASC";
  $result = executeSQL($sql, array(':country' => $country));
  if (is_array($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $record) {
        $output = '<option value="' . htmlentities($record["state"], ENT_QUOTES) . '" ';
        if($state == $record["state"]) {
            $output .= " selected";
            error_log("TRUE");
        } else {
            error_log("FALSE");
        }
        $output .= '>' . htmlentities($record["state"], ENT_QUOTES) . '</option>';
        error_log("'".$state."' == '".$record["state"]."'"); 
        echo $output;
    }
  }
}
```